# How to return the array in recursive function in php

Tags: php, recursion, store

### I'm trying to handle the recursive array in PHP. But my code is working fine. Problem is I'm unable to store the results in one array and return.

See the code:

```
function array_recursion(array $myarray, array $searchterms){
   //empty array
   $tempArr = array();
       //loop through $myarray
            foreach ($myarray as $key => $value){
                if (is_array($value)){
                  array_recursion($value, $searchterms);
                } 
                else if (in_array($key, $searchterms)){
                  print str_replace("0:", "", ($key . ": " . $value . "\n"));
                }
            }
        }
   //Call the function
    $finalValue = array_recursion($arr, Array('VCHKEY','VOUCHERTYPENAME','VOUCHERNUMBER','PARTYNAME','NARRATION','REFERENCE','AMOUNT','VCHTYPE'));
    //but this should print empty array
    print_r($finalValue);die();
```

I want to use the below two lines in the above function

```
$tempArr[] = str_replace("0:", "", ($key . ": " . $value . "\n"));
return $tempArr;
```

What is the actual issue? Can anyone help to figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a small example of what `$arr` you are passing in.

Comment: and could you show what should be in $finalValue?

Comment: $arr = Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [TALLYREQUEST] => Import Data ) [1] => Array ( [IMPORTDATA] => Array ( [REQUESTDESC] => Array ( [REPORTNAME] => All Masters [STATICVARIABLES] => Array ( [SVCURRENTCOMPANY] => Milan ) ) [REQUESTDATA] => Array ( [TALLYMESSAGE] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [VOUCHER] => Array ( [@attributes] => Array ( [REMOTEID] => cef6921e-7882-4b3f-8b48-900165ecba3b-00000026 [VCHKEY] => cef6921e-7882-4b3f-8b48-900165ecba3b-0000aada:00000040 [VCHTYPE] => Sales Order [ACTION] => Create [OBJVIEW] => Invoice Voucher View )

Comment: $finalValue = VCHKEY: cef6921e-7882-4b3f-8b48-900165ecba3b-0000aada:00000040 Array ( ) VCHTYPE: Sales Order Array ( ) hjvb Array ( ) NARRATION: skdbjfhos Array ( ) PARTYNAME: Cash Array ( ) VOUCHERTYPENAME: Sales Order.

Comment: $arr and $finalValue i gave you a small part only.

Comment: All of these relevant details should be transferred to the question body as an [edit] -- this would contibute to the [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution to return the value as array using recursion method.Check the below code.

```
 function array_value_recursive(array $key, array $arr){
    $val = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($va, $ke) use($key, &$val){
        if(in_array($ke,$key))
         array_push($val, $va);
    });
    return count($val) > 1 ? $val : array_pop($val);
  }
```

Hope this will help someone.